# Put images with text as ticklabels with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart, data-visualization

How can I put local image files as tickslabels and the country name under the flag using `ggplot2`?

I would like to achive something like this:

[image]

The data looks like:

```
countries = c("Norway", "Spain", "Germany", "Canada", "China")
values = c(10, 20, 30, 22, 19)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at the ggtext package: https://wilkelab.org/ggtext/. In particular the second example they give.

Comment: @teunbrand it looks good, thank you!

Comment: Vectors in R are defined with the [combine function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/c).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite sure, the `ggtext` solution is way easier. Just for completeness, you could also do the following. Brings some additional dependencies though:

```
library(cowplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(magick)
df <- data.frame(countries = c("Norway", "Spain", "Germany", "Canada", "China"),
                 values = c(10, 20, 30, 22, 19))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = countries, y = values))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  theme_bw()

pimage <- axis_canvas(p, axis = 'x')+
  cowplot::draw_image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Flag_of_Canada_%28Pantone%29.svg/320px-Flag_of_Canada_%28Pantone%29.svg.png", x = 0.5, scale = 0.5)+
  cowplot::draw_image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg/640px-Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg.png", x = 1.5, scale = 0.5)+
  cowplot::draw_image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/ba/Flag_of_Germany.svg/320px-Flag_of_Germany.svg.png", x = 2.5, scale = 0.5)+
  cowplot::draw_image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Flag_of_Norway.svg/320px-Flag_of_Norway.svg.png", x = 3.5, scale = 0.5)+
  cowplot::draw_image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9a/Flag_of_Spain.svg/320px-Flag_of_Spain.svg.png", x = 4.5, scale = 0.5)
  

ggdraw(insert_xaxis_grob(p, pimage, position = "center"))
```

[image]